# Make php method available from outside root/index.php

Tags: php

Im having an issue exposing a function to other php files. I would like to allow another php file to access a method from essentially root/index.php, or just /index.php. However when i use include('/index.php') it instead includes the index.php file from the current directory i.e /search/index.php or /latest/index.php

Ultimately what im trying to solve is how to call a method stored in my /index.php file from root/mydirectory/index.php:

```
//root/mydirectory/index.php
<?php
   include('/index.php');
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    runMethod($log);//function i want to call, defined in regular /index.php file
} else {
}

?>
```

method in root/index.php

```
function runMethod($log) {
}
```

Is there a simple way to share this method without using a global.php file or to just expose the method from the root/index.php file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `method as in class method` or do you mean a function?

Comment: a function sorry i'll try to clear that up in the description

Comment: Please provide absolute path of file to include. Use `__FILE__` to get current file path and `dirname(__FILE__)` to get current folder name where you are running script

Comment: What else is in the `index.php` file you want to include

Comment: just the function runMethod and the variable to be passed into it which is also contained in root/index.php, which is a database reference.

Comment: Can I suggest a better solution would be to create a `utils.php` script with this and any other helper functions you may decide to write. `index.php` as other conortations that will confuse you and other developers that may work on your code later

Comment: Rishi the __FILE__ is C:\xampp\htdocs\mydirectory\index.php and the dirname(__FILE__) is C:\xampp\htdocs\mydirectory however the file i wish to include from is just htdocs/index.php

Comment: But your main problem is the use of the BACKSLASH as the first character this says go to the root folder of the drive and look for a file called `index.php` so to go one folder back up the directory structure use `include '../index.php'` and 2 folders back use `'../../index.php'`

Comment: @Dean219 :  you can use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: Ok some incredible feedback, thanks Riggs for the recommendation and rishi for the path help. Both helped me tons and iv already fixed the issue with the help from you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your file like this

```
include("../index.php"); // one folder up to the current folder
```

Comment: This answer and @RiggsFolly and Rishi are what solve the issue. Thanks to you all.